# Colorbox unable to display dynamically generated image

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, colorbox, mime-types

I have a gallery system that generates images of different sizes and caches them outside of the webroot.
I then have a wrapper template in ColdFusion that displays the image based on an ID and size parameters.
So for instance, a URL might be `'/dspImage.cfm?imageID=123&w=600'`.
This would return the content for image number `123` at a width of `600px`.

This all works perfectly, however when attempting to use the Colorbox jquery plugin, it seems unable to display images served in this way, instead returning a whole bunch of text and control characters, as if unable to recognise the mime type of the JPG file.

The browser displays the image with no issues, and I've been using this technique for almost a decade now with no issues, but Colorbox seems unable to handle it.
If I link to the JPG directly, it works fine in Colorbox.

I have had other lightbox plugins working ok with this image serving technique, but I like colorbox and I'm loathe to use another lightbox if I can help it.

*Does anyone have any suggestions?*

For reference, the headers sent back from the image serving script are:

```
Content-Length  178856
Content-Type    image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
Date    Sun, 12 Aug 2012 15:07:54 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

I notice that when hitting the image directly via colorbox request headers contain:

```
Accept  image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
```

However, if I hit the image serving script via colourbox, this becomes:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

I thought this might indicate the problem, until I tried both the serving script, and the image directly, via the browser and it too showed:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Hope that's enough info, and makes sense to someone!

Comment: A live example would be cool... failing htat, can you show some example HTML that you are using to link the colorbox?

Comment: For me this problem came down to the order of the query string parameters I was using (it wanted the file extension at the end). I reordered mine, but I'm sure the solution below would do the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your ColorBox settings, try setting the photo=true

```
$("#cboxDiv").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#dynURL#", photo:true});
```

Ref: [ColorBox Docs](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)